# ReqEx to transfer a string to a qualified double string with thousends separator and comma

Tags: regex, format

I need a regex expression to sort out any thousends separators and keep the comma. Also the following zeros should be sorted out.

So `123.456,7890000` should convert to `123456,789`

With `(?=.*?)(.*?[1-9])(?!.*?\.)(?=0*$)|^.*$` i get the `123.456,789`.

Now the question is how to eliminate the "**.**"?

Comment: Remove the dots as  a post-processing step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replacement method/function with

```
[^\d,]|(,\d*?[1-9])0+$
```

and `$1` (or `\1`) replacement pattern that will keep the contents of Group 1 in the string (see explanation below).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWOjxJ/1).

**Details**

- `[^\d,]` - any char other than digit and comma
- `|` - or
- `(,\d*?[1-9])` - Group 1: a comma, any zero or more digits as few as possible
- `0+$` - one or more `0`s at the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, Wiktor. I use your first hint and remove the dots in a pre processing step. Your second answer does not work for me. I use the match and not the replace way with regex. And the first dot is found, but not removed. So i dont get my needed number as the result. The first match is the postion of the first dot.